# WSO2 IS how to enable webhooks to external service on user's claims change

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there any way to send webhooks to external service on user's claims changing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently WSO2IS does not have in built capability to send webhooks to an external service.
But based on your requirements you can write a custom event handler[1] and subscribe it to the events you need to capture, process those events and publish the event data to the external service.

In your case you can write a custom event handler to subscribe ‘POST_SET_USER_CLAIMS’ event to capture user claim changes and publish the data to the external service you need.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/user-mgt/write-a-custom-event-handler/